# Iterating through an array, adding occurrances of a true

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I've Been looking around a bit but unsure i'm searching for the right thing.

Say i have this

```
array ['f', 't', 'f', 't', 't', 't', 'f', 'f', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'f', 't']
```

(I have an array of true/false in postgresql which i've used to import to javascript, and it's come back as 't's and 'f's)

I'm looking to change that array to

```
[1, 3, 6, 1] (adding all the trues in between false)
```

Assuming there's some sort of super obvious way I've completely missed!

Comment: You want "t"s "in between" "f"s but you count the "t" at the very end which is not in between "f"s. What exactly do you want..?

Comment: Sorry, in between wasn't the right description, just all of the grouped up trues to be added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby:

```
arr.join.scan(/t+/).map(&:size)
=> [1, 3, 6, 1]
```

JavaScript:

```
arr.join('').match(/t+/gi).map(function(str) {
  return str.length
});
```

```js
var arr = ['f', 't', 'f', 't', 't', 't', 'f', 'f', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'f', 't'];
sizes = arr.join('').match(/t+/gi).map(function(str) {
    return str.length;
});
console.log(sizes);
```

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, "...and it's come back as 't's and 'f's"

Answer (score 0):

A proposal with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
function countT(array) {
    var r = [];
    array.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
        a === 'f' || aa[i - 1] === 't' && ++r[r.length - 1] || r.push(1);
    });
    return r;
}

console.log(countT(['f', 't', 'f', 't', 't', 't', 'f', 'f', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'f', 't']));
console.log(countT(["t", "f", "t"]));
console.log(countT(["f", "f"]));
console.log(countT(["f", "t"]));
console.log(countT(["t", "f"]));
console.log(countT(["t", "t"]));
```

Comment: test with ["t","f","t"] i haven't checked the others though.

Comment: @Redu, please check again.

Comment: ["t","f","t"] should return empty. OP says (adding all the trues "in between" false)

Comment: @Redu, the given result for the first array would be wrong too.

Comment: Yes definitely deceiving question i have deleted my answer up until clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** method in JavaScript

```js
var arr = ['f', 't', 'f', 't', 't', 't', 'f', 'f', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'f', 't'];

var res = arr.reduce(function(result, e) {
  if (e == 't') { // check value is `t` and increment the last element in array
    result[result.length - 1] ++;
  } else if (result[result.length - 1] != 0) { // if element is `f` and last eleemnt is not zero then push 0 to the array
    result.push(0);
  }
  return result;
}, [0])

console.log(res);
```

---

You can reduce number of lines using [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and [Logical Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation).

```js
var arr = ['f', 't', 'f', 't', 't', 't', 'f', 'f', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'f', 't'];

var res = arr.reduce((r, e) => {
  e == 't' ? r[r.length - 1] ++ : r[r.length - 1] == 0 || r.push(0);
  return r;
}, [0])
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question has a deception. Although it clearly states that the true values "in-between" the false values are counted in his provided example it is not the case and the last item "t" is counted even though it is not followed by a "f". So i have two solutions here. This one satisfies the example.

```js
var a = ['f', 't', 'f', 't', 't', 't', 'f', 'f', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'f', 't'],
 code = a.reduce((p,c) => (c == "t" ? p[p.length-1]++ : !!p[p.length-1] && p.push(0),p), [0]);
console.log(code);
```

And this one satisfies the literal description of the question.

```js
var a = ['t', 'f', 't', 'f', 't', 't', 't', 'f', 'f', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'f', 't'],
    r = [],
    n = 0;
    a.reduce((p,c) => (p != c ? c == "t" ? n++
                                         : n && (r.push(n),n=0)
                              : c == "t" && n++
                      ,c));
console.log(r);
```

Comment: Yes that means you have 0 trues between falses.

Comment: you can see it this way ... ;-)